# Progress Dialog and orientation changed

Tags: android

I'm facing some problems with the progress dialogs. I use a managed progress dialog to show the user that an operation is being carried out with the following code written in the onCreateDialog(int id) function:

```
          case PROGRESS_DIALOG :
            {
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);                                      
                dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.eStrUpdating));
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
                {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface)
                    {
                       Log.i(TAG,"progress dialog cancelled ");
                    }
                });
                return dialog;
            }
```

When the operation completes I call dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG). The problem is that if I rotate the phone while the progress dialog is displayed then when the operation completes the dismiss call has no effect and the progress remains showing. And this I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you rotate the phone, the Activity is destroy and recreated. Then you should call dismiss on your dialog, in the onDestroy method of your activity and recreate it.

Comment: Well the thing is that the dialog is managed by the activity , and the activity should handle things like dismissing it when the activity is destroyed and showing it when it is created/resumed.

Comment: I think the dismiss has no effect because when you rotate, as I said, a new instance of Activity is created, so I suppose a new dialog too. so maybe you are trying to do the dismiss on the previous dialog?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above answer.  When your orientation is changed your activity is destroyed and recreated.

My experience with orientation change is:

- my dialog does not automatically get
  dismissed, but it seems to visually
  disappear just the same (possible
  leak?)
- I maintain an instance variable for the
  dialog in the activity and check for
  null to see if the dialog is showing
  in both onDestroy and
  onSaveInstanceState
- I dismiss the dialog in onDestroy
- I implement an
  DialogInterface.onDismissListener so
  I can see when the dialog is
  dismissed (perhaps by user request )
- I write a boolean in
  onSaveInstanceState ( the boolean
  indicates the dialog was showing )
- in the activity's onCreate I look for
  this boolean in the bundle and
  call showDialog again

HTH.